# Hive gives a record by ‘distinct’ clause, but ‘count’ is 0

Tags: sql, hadoop

look at these.

```
0: jdbc:hive2> select distinct A_COL from A_TABLE where A_COL='1999-05-04';
+-------------+--+
|    A_COL    |
+-------------+--+
| 1999-05-04  |
+-------------+--+
1 row selected (6.127 seconds)

0: jdbc:hive2> select count(*) from A_TABLE where A_COL='1999-05-04';
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 0    |
+------+--+
1 row selected (4.206 seconds)

0: jdbc:hive2> select * from A_TABLE where A_COL='1999-05-04';
+-------+---------------
| A_COL | blabla...
+-------+----------
+-------+----------
No rows selected (0.292 seconds)
```

I think the first query means ‘at least one record whose A_COL’s value is '1999-05-04' exists.’
But the second and third query deny that.

How can it be possible?

Comment: This suggests that the underlying data is changing.  Those query results should not be occurring on a static database.

Comment: Do you think the difference in run times might be significant? Its almost as if the first two queries actually did something, whilst the third didn't bother.

Comment: `show partitions A_TABLE` - what is output of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your table has partition on column `A_COL` or not but this can be the case. so the distinct is showing partition value for it but table has NO actual data:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE test_2(B_COL string) PARTITIONED BY (A_COL string);
OK
Time taken: 1.182 seconds

hive> ALTER TABLE test_2 ADD PARTITION (A_COL='2016-07-27');
OK
Time taken: 0.285 seconds

hive> select count(*) from test_2 where A_COL='2016-07-27';
OK
0
Time taken: 35.016 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select * from test_2 where A_COL='2016-07-27';
OK
Time taken: 0.165 seconds

hive> select distinct(A_COL) from test_2;
2016-07-27
Time taken: 24.528 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: You’re right! That partition exists (with no actual data).
(But is this behavior intended by HIVE? this looks very wired.)

Comment: there are no documentation on it but - [HIVE-3108](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3108?focusedCommentId=13402814&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13402814) and [HIVE-2955](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2955) - there can be other tickets on similar topic.